# How does electron application record memory usage

Tags: memory-management, electron

I use `Performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize`, it shows that the memory usage is 1259219671 Bytes. But when I open the memory panel of devtools, it shows that "total js heap size" is 70MB. Why is there such a big difference between these two numbers?

I want to record the memory usage of the current application and keep it down, and record the value again after optimization, and compare the two recorded values ​​​​through the graph, so I need to get an exact number to save. Is `Performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize` reliable?

Comment: The question is not whether it's "reliable" (however you would measure *that*), but rather if it's a useful metric. I find 1,2+ GB of used heap a little unrealistic tbh, but also you're comparing apples and pears here: `Performance.memory.totalJSHeapSize` *should* be closer to the "total JS heap size" the devtools are showing. Note that you're not measuring your app's memory performance here though, just that of your *renderer process*. Even for that, there's a new API, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/memory).

Comment: This is an even better modern API to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measureUserAgentSpecificMemory but unfortunately it currently has issues within electron: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/37147